# How do I debug a Delayed::Worker.work_off that doesn't return success or failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, delayed-job

I am testing my Delayed::Job using Rspec.

In my rspec_controller:

```
  it "queues up delayed job and fires" do
    setup        
    expect {
    post :create, {:job => valid_attributes}
    }.to change(Delayed::Job, :count).by(2)     

    Delayed::Worker.new.work_off.should == [2,0]

  end
```

Delayed::Job.count passes as expected, but Delayed::Worker.new.work_off returns as [0,0], indicating there are 0 successes and 0 failures when there are 2 jobs.

How should I debug to find out why work_off doesn't fire the jobs.

**Edit**: The 2 jobs that are supposed to run, have their run_at set into the future. Does work_off fire off jobs that are not meant to be immediate?

Answer (score 0):

Although this could be an older question, there's one parameter that's not much documented, try using

```
Delayed::Worker.new(quiet: false).work_off
```

to debug the result of your background jobs, this could help you to find out if the fact that they're supposed to run in the future is messing with the assert itself.

EDIT: Don't forget to take off the "quiet:false" when you're done, otherwise your tests will always output the results of the background jobs.

Answer (score 0):

The construct

```
Delayed::Worker.new.work_off
```

immediately processes everything that is in the DJ queue, and in the same thread as the caller (it doesn't spawn a separate worker thread).  But this doesn't explain why you're not getting [2, 0] for a result.

To answer your original question 'How should I debug to find out why work_off doesn't fire the jobs?', I suggest you use the callback hooks to trace the lifecycle of the jobs.  Add a comment if you need to be shown how to do that... :)

Comment: I am was using Delayed::Worker.new(options).work_off in my test cases. But suddenly it stopped working. How can i debug it?